# Java, method name via reflection for logging

Tags: java, android, logging, reflection, method-names

Working on a quick logging utility method. Normally I would use Aspects for this but working in the Android SDK where there isnt support for that.

How would I go about grabbing a method name in a generic way using reflection?

Also any performance hit in java with reflection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will probably work:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()
```

Comment: Thanks, going to try this out. Question: if I was to call this from a generic utility method, technically the methodName I would need would be in the caller method, I should be able just grab the previous stack frame from .getStackTrace ?

Comment: Yep. Every method call is a stack frame.

Comment: what about performance? if i am logging at minimum two places in every method in every class how much overhead is this going to be?

Comment: No idea. Probably not enough to worry about, since I don't think it's actually reflection per se.