# I would like to get MethodName in my report

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-extent-report

I am trying to logged my called method name in report when i am creating node.

I tried it with `getname()`, `Method.GetMethodName` in `ITestresult` but not getting proper way to find out.

```
public static class Reports 
{
    public static void CreateNode(String Description)
    {
        test.createNode(Description);
    }
}



public static Class ModuleClass
{
    public static void Login()
    {
        Reports.CreateNode( ???": method started");
    }
}
```

In  question mark area i would like my method name which printed in report.

Out put like should be -

```
Login : method started in report.
```

it is not regarding logging. It base on any method i call from my test library of any specific module.Let's assume there is one method which filling form like below :

```
public static Class ModuleClass
    {
        public static void FormFilled()
        {
            Reports.CreateNode( ???": method started");
        }
    }
```

so when i called this method in my execution class like below :

```
@Test
public void SavingForm()
{
    ModuleClass.FormFilled();
}
```

then after execution in report i should get :

```
output FormFilled : method started
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, method name via reflection for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948076/java-method-name-via-reflection-for-logging)

Answer (score 1):

I m getting output by using below line :

new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()

```
public static Class ModuleClass
    {
        public static void FormFilled()
        {
            Reports.CreateNode( new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() 
 + ": method started");
        }
    }
```